# Remove an Item from a dropdownlist and add it to another dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have one dropdownlist filled with country list and another dropdownlist empty, I have a 2 buttons > >>

When I press the > button I want to add a country from country dropdownlist to emptydropdown list ony by one (the ones which are selected) and when I press the >> I want add the countries add to empty dropdownlist. And each time It adds it should be removed from the first dropdown list too.

I tried:

```
 $("#form_selectednationality_id").add($("#form_nationality_id option:selected"));
 $("#form_nationality_id option:selected").remove();
```

it removes the item succefully but doesn't add anything
Do you have any comment or idea?
thanks.

Comment: How much you will pay for this task? :)

Comment: [#gimmethecodez](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question)

Comment: :D Well :D I'm penyless sitar plyer, and penyless sitarplayers don't have much money! :D

Comment: use 'append' to add an option to the drop down list and use 'remove' to delete the option. Try it and tell us    :)

Comment: I tried this :  $("#form_selectednationality_id").add($("#form_nationality_id option:selected"));
            $("#form_nationality_id option:selected").remove(); but it remove the item but doesn't add anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this??

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#countryButton").click(function () {
            $("#second").append($("<option/>", { html: $("#first").val(),value:$("#first").val(), selected: true }));
            $('#first option:selected').remove();

        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <select id="first">
        <option>country1</option>
        <option>country2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="countryButton" value=">" />
    <select id="second">
    </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that it shows the value of the #1 in the #2 item, I want to show it exactly like it was in the #1 show the name and have the same value

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $("#2").append(new Option($("#1 option:selected").val()));
    });
});
</script>

<select id="1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="add" value="add">
<select id="2"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that it shows the value of the #1 in the #2 item, I want to show it exactly like it was in the #1 show the name and have the same value